# JUnit 5: Assert an exception is thrown fails with an error

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, powermockito, junit5

I am working on writing unit test cases for my DAO using the Junit5. I want to test whether the `BadRequestException` is thrown when maximum template reached and check whether `NotFoundException` is thrown when template is not found. But I am getting the following exception:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.

My code:

`TemplateDao.java`:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public MyTemplateDetailsView getTemplateDetails(Long templateId) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    MyTemplate myTemplate = getTemplate(templateId);
    if (null == myTemplate || myTemplate.getStatus() != TemplateStatus.ACTIVE.value) {
        throw new NotFoundException("template.not.found");
    }

    Integer templatesCount = getTempletsCount(templateId);
    if (templatesCount > templateLimit) {
        LOGGER.info("max template count reacged");
        throw new BadRequestException("template.limit.exceded");
    }
 }
```

`TemplateDaoTest.java`:

```
@Test 
void getTemplateDetails_ThrowsNotFoundException_IfTemplateNotinActiveStatus() {

    Assertions.assertThrows(NotFoundException.class, () -> {
       when(templateDao.getTemplate(anyLong())).thenReturn(null);
    });

}

@Test 
public void getTemplateDetails_ThrowsBadRequestException_IfTemplateLimitExceeded() {

    Integer limit = 100;
    assertThrows(BadRequestException.class, () -> {
        when(templateDao.getTempletsCount(anyLong())).thenReturn(limit);
        templateDao.getTemplateDetails(anyLong);
    });
}
```

Comment: Add breakets to `anyLong` in your last code line.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is in the following block of code:

```
assertThrows(BadRequestException.class, () -> {
    when(templateDao.getTempletsCount(anyLong())).thenReturn(limit);
    templateDao.getTemplateDetails(anyLong);
});
```

I'm not sure where the `anyLong` comes from, so I'll make an assumption that you meant `anyLong()`, as in `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyLong`.

If so, the problem with this is that you're trying to use a `Matcher` instead of a concrete value outside of stubbing context (i.e. outside of the specification of what method should return when called).

You need to pass in a proper `Long`, i.e. `150L` (or whatever is larger than `templateLimit`) when you're calling your stubbed method. For example:

```
assertThrows(BadRequestException.class, () -> {
    when(templateDao.getTempletsCount(anyLong())).thenReturn(limit);
    templateDao.getTemplateDetails(150L); // note the concrete value
});
```

---

It's actually fairly trivial to reproduce if you're inclined to do so (I'm using JUnit 4, but it should be okay with JUnit 5, too):

```
public class MatchersTest {

    @Test
    public void testConversion() {
        Converter converter = new Converter();

        when(converter.from(anyLong())).thenReturn("1");

        converter.from(anyLong());
    }

    private static class Converter {
        String from(Long number) {
            return String.valueOf(number);
        }
    }
}
```